# Is there ever any reason to use padding-top and padding-bottom for inline elements?

Tags: html, css, padding

According to http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/, the section called "Inline elements and padding" says

> While padding can be applied to all sides of an inline element, only left and right padding will have an effect on surrounding content.

So in accordance with that, it seems that it is never ever any point to use padding vertical(top,bottom) for inline elements.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the padding box is the area covered with the background colour, and the border is painted around that, so changing the padding top and bottom can change what the inline element looks like even if it has no effect on the surrounding content.